# How to write xml document in specified location in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, filestream

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement elem = xmldoc.CreateElement("Root");
elem.SetAttribute("NAME", "KARTHIK");
elem.SetAttribute("NO", "9859");
xmldoc.Save(@"D:\kk.xml");
```

i unable to save XML document in to this specified location. help me.

Comment: Can you try some other location?

Comment: You may want to check if you have write permission to the root of drive D:

Answer (score 1):

You never add the element you create to the document, call:

```
xmldoc.AppendChild(elem);
```

Before `.Save()` as currently your attempt to save a document with no root will fail.

Comment: Very good point. Save works only if the XML document is well formed